# Get Value of column by API in angular

Tags: angularjs, api

I want to get status value from API in my grid made in angular js. Below is the code, I applied in my view file:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in list">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td class="text-center" ng-init="statusUpdate(item.id ,$index)">
        </td>
        <td>{{myVar[$index]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Then in my controller I added:

```
app.controller('MerchantController', function ($scope, MerchantService, Alert, toaster) {
   $scope.statusUpdate = function (id, index) {
   var api = MerchantService.statusUpdate(id, index).then(function (response) {

            console.log($scope.myVar[index]);
            $scope.myVar[index] = response.data;
            console.log($scope.myVar[index]);
    });
};
});
```

In my service file, I added:

```
app.service('MerchantService', function(API, $stateParams, $q,$http) {
this.statusUpdate = function(item,index) {
    return $http({
        url: 'http://10.10.10.7/petca_magento/integration/vendor/vendor/id/' + item,
        method: "GET",
    });
    };
});
```

I want to get of status field dynamically based on the user id in {{myVar[$index]}}

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What do you expect to happen vs. what actually happens? :)

Comment: I expect to get value of status, but I am getting an error in console $scope.myVar is undefined

Comment: You haven't declared myVar. Try to declare it before the service API call to an empty array, for instance. You also have a console.log before attaching values to myVar so it may cause an error.